# Type Error: c is not a constructor/c.widget is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, jquery-ui-widget

I am trying to get **jQuery UI dialogs** working on my **drupal** site. After checking the web console, I found that I was getting the error:

> $(...).dialog is not a function

I did some researching (aka. googling) and I found that this could have been because I didn't add all the necessary `js` files to my drupal page. So I added `jquery.ui.dialog.min.js` and all of its dependencies. However, I am now getting the:

> Type Errors: c is not a constructor and c.widget is not a function.

Since `jquery.ui.widget.min.js` doesn't depend on anything, I am not sure what to do...

also I haven't found any conclusive answers to these errors...

**EDIT:** js files added (in order):

```
jquery.ui.widget.min.js
jquery.ui.dialog.min.js
jquery.ui.button.min.js
jquery.ui.draggable.min.js
jquery.ui.mouse.min.js
jquery.ui.position.min.js
jquery.ui.resizable.min.js
my_module.js
```

Comment: Can you post a list of all the jquery scripts you've included on the page and the order they're in?

Comment: maybe also share your link of the actual page

Comment: I posted the scripts in order. I changed them from how I had them originally...I thought maybe that was the issue. It now only gives the `c is not a constructor` error. Also, vishal, what link?

Comment: Would be the best, to set up a public demo site. Btw: Have you included jQuery itself?

Comment: `jQuery.js` and `jquery.ui.core.min.js` were automatically already there...all of those scripts were suppose to be included automatically too...

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Just added:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui');
```

Instead of each script separately.